# How to include jsp file in a sub directory with relative images paths to root index file

Tags: html, image, jsp, include, absolute-path

I have the index.html file with images stored at the same directory:

- home.jsp
- sub-dir

  - index.html
  - image.jpeg

and sub-dir content is a file uploaded by the user so in the index.html the image path is directly img src="image.jpeg" i need to include this index html to the home.jsp with the image preview.

Comment: Give a path of image file like this, <img src="subdirpath/image.jpg">

Comment: No its a manually uploaded file which contains the index.html and image file and assuming the path is unknown. As an example its a slider manually uploaded to a particular location and it is imported to the home.